# Ошибка invalid syntax в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

**Python 3.6 (32 bit)**
выходит ошибка в этом коде

```
import random as r
import os
names = ["Валерий", "Илья", "Семен", "Александр", "Вячеслав", "Роман"]
names2 = ["Лещенко", "Новосёлов", "Газизуллин", "Плотников", "Колесников"]
os.system("md lol")
os.system("cd lol")
for i in range(154, 8950):
    name = r.randint(0, 5)
    name2 = r.randint(0, 4)
    cost = (r.randint(468, 987)
    os.system("copy con ", i, "_Слитых_кошельков_киви.txt")
    os.system("---")

invalid syntax line 11 os.system('copy con...')
                        ↑
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас лишняя открывающая скобка в строке с `cost`, что сломало код на следующей строке, т.к. у той есть закрывающая скобка.

Плюс, [os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) принимает один аргумент -- команду как строку, а у вас аргументов несколько. Объедините их в одну строку.

Пример:

```
cost = r.randint(468, 987)
os.system("copy con {}_Слитых_кошельков_киви.txt".format(i))
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно как-то сделать, чтобы после команды copy con, не запускался инпут в cmd, а вводилась туда информация, которую ты сам укажешь в своем коде?

Comment: @EnjJoe, лучше используйте функцию `open` для записи в файл